# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}> after adding React-native-web

Tags: react-native, react-native-web, webpack.config.js

May be a basic question but I've been struggling with it for over a week.

I just added React Native Web to my existing React Native Application but when I try to run in:

1. Run Docker
2. Run Metro (

```
npx react native start
```

)

3. Run Web (

```
npm run web
```

)

I get this error:

```
> dashborad@0.0.1 web

> webpack serve -d source-map --mode development --config "./web/webpack.config.js" --color --hot

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/

<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://145.93.124.189:8080/

<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv6): http://[fe80::1]:8080/

<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/Users/ondrahruby/Documents/Fontys/Semester4Part3/SOFA/Smart-Bumper-Dashboard/Implementation/dashborad/public' directory

asset bundle.web.js 1.62 MiB [emitted] (name: main) 1 related asset

runtime modules 27.5 KiB 13 modules

orphan modules 234 bytes [orphan] 1 module

modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.46 MiB 135 modules

./index.web.js 507 bytes [built] [code generated]

./App.jsx 5.85 KiB [built] [code generated] [1 error]

./app.json 56 bytes [built] [code generated]

ERROR in ./App.jsx 105:8

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (105:8)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

| // List wrapper

| return (

> <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

| <View style={styles.listTab}>

| {listTab.map(e => (

@ ./index.web.js 1:261-277

webpack 5.85.1 compiled with 1 error in 709 ms
```

My webpack,config.js file:

```
const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

const appDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../');

// This is needed for webpack to compile JavaScript.

// Many OSS React Native packages are not compiled to ES5 before being

// published. If you depend on uncompiled packages they may cause webpack build

// errors. To fix this webpack can be configured to compile to the necessary

// \node_module\.`

const babelLoaderConfiguration = {test: /.(js|jsx)$/,

exclude: /node_modules/,

// Add every directory that needs to be compiled by Babel during the build.

include: [path.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),

//path.resolve(appDirectory, 'src'),

path.resolve(appDirectory, 'node_modules/react-native-uncompiled'),],

use: {loader: 'babel-loader',options: {cacheDirectory: true,

// The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager

presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-react'],

// Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app

plugins: ['react-native-web',['module-resolver',{

alias: {'react-native$': 'react-native-web',},},],],},},};

// This is needed for webpack to import static images in JavaScript files.

const imageLoaderConfiguration = {

test: /.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,

use: {loader: 'url-loader',

options: {name: '[name].[ext]',esModule: false,},},};

module.exports = {entry: [// load any web API polyfills

// path.resolve(appDirectory, 'polyfills-web.js'),

// your web-specific entry filepath.resolve(appDirectory, 'index.web.js'),],

// configures where the build ends up

output: {

filename: 'bundle.web.js',

path: path.resolve(appDirectory, 'dist'),},

// ...the rest of your config

module: {rules: [babelLoaderConfiguration, imageLoaderConfiguration],},

resolve: {

// This will only alias the exact import "react-native"

alias: {'react-native$': 'react-native-web',},

// If you're working on a multi-platform React Native app, web-specific

// module implementations should be written in files using the extension

// .web.js.

extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],},};``
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/ondrahruby/smartbumper/tree/main/Smart-Bumper-Dashboard-SSBD-66-Create-web-app).

I expect the App to run in the browser and the page that should be opened should show available and occupied docks.
I tried modifying the webpack.config.js file to be able to take js and jsx files but the problem perisists